# What is the Semantic-UI equivalent of Bootstrap's 'sr-only'?

Tags: semantic-ui, screen-readers

I can't find the utility class to **hide content to user but show to screen reader** in [Semantic-UI](http://semantic-ui.com/).

What is the Semantic-ui equivalent of Bootstrap’s `sr-only`?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure that exists in semantic-ui. A work around is to create a class like so (copied from bootstrap's scaffolding.less #129):

```
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
  border: 0;
}
```